# Difference between Pattern.asMatchPredicate and Pattern.asPredicate

Tags: java, regex, java-11

Java 11 added some new methods to the `Pattern` class (a compiled version of a regular expression), including:

- [`asPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#asPredicate())
- [`asMatchPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#asMatchPredicate())

I am trying to understand the difference between the two and when I would want to use one over the other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- `Pattern.asPredicate` will return true if **any part of the input string** matches the Regular expression. You should use this method if you're testing some larger body of text for a certain pattern. For example, to test whether a comment from a user contains a hyperlink.
- `Pattern.asMatchPredicate` will return true if **the entire input string** matches the Regular expression. You should use this method if you're testing the entire input for a certain pattern. For example, to validate the phone number of a user in their profile.

`Pattern.asPredicate` internally uses [`Matcher.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()), while `Pattern.asMatchPrediate` internally uses [`Matcher.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()). So the difference between the two boils down to the difference between these two methods from the `Matcher` class.

Below are some examples to showcase the difference. You can copy & paste below code in an online Java sandbox like https://www.compilejava.net/ to play around with it yourself.

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("abc");

        // asPredicate will match any part of the input string
        Predicate<String> asPredicate = pattern.asPredicate();
        
        // True, because abc is part of abc
        System.out.printf("asPredicate: abc: %s\n", asPredicate.test("abc"));

        // True, because abc is part of abcabc
        System.out.printf("asPredicate: abcabc: %s\n", asPredicate.test("abcabc"));

        // True, because abc is part of 123abc123
        System.out.printf("asPredicate: 123abc123: %s\n", asPredicate.test("123abc123"));

        // False, because abc is NOT part of 123
        System.out.printf("asPredicate: 123: %s\n", asPredicate.test("123")); // -> false

        // asMatchPredicate will only match the entire input string
        Predicate<String> asMatchPredicate = pattern.asMatchPredicate();

        // True, because abc exactly matches abc
        System.out.printf("asMatchPredicate: abc: %s\n", asMatchPredicate.test("abc"));

        // False, because abc does not exactly match abcabc
        System.out.printf("asMatchPredicate: abcabc: %s\n", asMatchPredicate.test("abcabc"));

        // False, because abc does not exactly match 123abc123
        System.out.printf("asMatchPredicate: 123abc123: %s\n", asMatchPredicate.test("123abc123"));

        // False, because abc does not exactly match 123
        System.out.printf("asMatchPredicate: 123: %s\n", asMatchPredicate.test("123"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `^` and `$` do not match line breaks unless the [multi-line mode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) has been turned on.

Comment: Would that mean that without multi-line mode `asPredicate` with `^abc$` is completely equivalent to `asMatchPredicate` with `abc`? I'm a little wary to make this statement, considering all the intricacies of Regex.

Comment: It *should* be equivalent, but it isn’t. I just made some tests and found a contradiction. Then, I searched the bug list and found that [I’m not the first one](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8218146). I think, explaining in terms of `^`  and `$` is not necessary. The semantics of `find` and `matches`, the operations also actually used under the hood, are more important and easier to remember as “`asMatchPredicate` uses `matches`”.

Comment: Looks like we are on the same path: I just wrote a series of tests and found several contradictions as well. I'll remove the bits comparing this to `^` and `$` since apparently they're *not* the same.. but the fact that they're different is a little confusing to me (and may warrant its own Q&A)

Comment: Here's a copy of the tests I wrote. https://pastebin.com/qJRu3YS5 Two contradictions I found are `"a\r"` and `"a\r\n"`, so specifically when the input ends with a line break.